# Changing relation between independent and dependent variable over time

Tags: regression, misspecification

I am currently trying to run a linear regression model where the effect of one of my independent variables (Xit) on my dependent variable (Yit) changes over time. Specifically, I suspect the independent variable (Xit) to affect the dependent variable (Yit) different in 2018 and affect the dependent variable different in 2019 once more (two breaks in the effect) (e.g. baseline effect of Xit on Yit of 4.0 for 2016-2017, effect of Xit on Yit of 5.0 in 2018 and effect of Xit on Yit of 6.0 in 2019).

I currently included the independent variable (Xit) and an interaction with a dummy variable (Dummyt) (0 for 2016 and 2017, 1 for 2018 and 2 for 2019).

However I do not know if this is the right approach.

I also dont know whether I should include the dummy variable (Dummyt) as a main effect (specification two below) or can just exclude it and only include the interaction term (Xit * Dummyt) (specification one below).

Regression equation:

(1) $Yit = \beta_0 + \beta_1Xit + \beta_2Xit*Dummy$t

or

(2) $Yit = \beta_0 + \beta_1Xit + \beta_2Dummyt + \beta_3Xit*Dummy$t

Sincerely,

Thomas

Comment: Where in either model is time represented, and how?

Comment: I represent time using a dummy variable that equals 0 for 2016 and 2017, 1 for 2018 and 2 for 2019.